# how can i convert two forms to components and adding components to view in angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, angular-reactive-forms

I have two forms that are currently running fine on same component.
as show in **InfoAndQualificationComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
@Component({
  selector: 'app-info-and-qualification',
  template: `<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="form.value">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="firstname" formControlName="firstname">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="lastname" formControlName="lastname">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group"style="margin-top:50px">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Qualification" formControlName="qualification">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Qualification type" formControlName="type">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"><button class="btn-primary">Submit</button></div>
</
})
export class InfoAndQualificationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  form = new FormGroup({
    firstname: new FormControl(),
    lastname: new FormControl(),
    qualification: new FormControl(),
    qtype: new FormControl(),
  });

  onSubmit(e)
  {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

But because of the clutters of code and the need for modularization (making the code smaller for easy update and debugging). i would like split these forms to two different sub components like so for **UserInfoComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-userinfo',
  template: `<form class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="form1" (ngSubmit)="form1.value">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="firstname" formControlName="firstname">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="lastname" formControlName="lastname">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group"><button class="btn-primary">Submit</button></div>
</form>`,

})
export class UserInfoComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  form1 = new FormGroup({
    firstname: new FormControl(),
    lastname: new FormControl(),
  });

  onSubmit(e)
  {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

and **UserQualificationComponent.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-qualification',
  template: `<form action="" class="form-horizontal" [formGroup]="form2"  (ngSubmit)="form2.value">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Qualification" formControlName="qualification">
  </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Qualification type" formControlName="qtype">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"><button class="btn-primary">Submit</button></div>
</form>`,
})
export class UserQualificationComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  form2 = new FormGroup({
    qualification: new FormControl(),
    qtype: new FormControl(),
  });

  onSubmit(e)
  {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

to be imported into one component maybe the **infoqualification.ts** like so

```
<app-userinfo></app-userinfo>
<div style="margin-top:50px">
  <app-qualification></app-qualification>
</div>
```

with their individual implementation in their seperate components and they should return value to the main component. 
Please Note i am quite new at angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ControlContainer

Documentation:https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlContainer

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlContainer, NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'address',
  template: `
    <fieldset ngModelGroup="address">
      <div>
        <label>Zip:</label>
        <input type="text" name="zip" ngModel>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Street:</label>
        <input type="text" name="street" ngModel>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>City:</label>
        <input type="text" name="city" ngModel>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  `,
  viewProviders: [ { provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: NgForm } ]
})
export class AddressComponent  {}
```

For More Details Check this:https://medium.com/@a.yurich.zuev/angular-nested-template-driven-form-4a3de2042475

Answer (score 1):

You are creating separate FormGroup for each Component. Would suggest create single Form Group in the parent component and pass as @Input() to child component. Using Form Group in child components we can add form controls.

Also you can create validation methods in each child components, which will be called from the parent component.

Code for Submit button and validation should be added in parent component.

Comment: here is a link to what i was doing https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m3bkxc. so you saying that i cant implement the submit button in each individual component.

Comment: We are not saying you cannot add submit button. You can add submit button in each component. But that will make your implementation complicated. You need to validate each component individually and finally you need to form the POST data to submit. IF you want to do that way. You can